# Loop though an array after ssh to a host in shell script

Tags: shell, ssh

In the part of my script, I need to make ssh to a host and delete the elements of an array. In my current code for each element of the array I need to make ssh to host which takes time. 
I want to make ssh to the host at one time and then delete all elements of the array.
How can I improve my below code from performance point of view?

```
for x in $Array
do
       echo "Value of array  are : $x"
       ssh user@abc.host.com "rm -rf $x"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Why the loop at all? Using `*` as subscript gives all elements of an array.

```
ssh user@example.com "rm -rf ${Array[*]}"
```

Note that either way (with or without loop) will break if file names contain whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You must input the commands in a file on your local, then upload the file, and finally run the script. Here is how it goes:

```
echo > rmscript.sh
for x in $Array
do
    echo "Value of array  are : $x"
    echo  "rm -rf $x" >> rmscript.sh
done
#upload
scp rmscript.sh user@abc.host.com:~
#run script
ssh user@abc.host.com "sh ~/rmscript.sh"
```